# Get result of function used in .on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function, lets name it `X1`, which returns variable Y. This function is used in action `.on("focusout", X1)`. How I can get variable `Y`? The result of `X1` when after executing `.on`?

Comment: `X1` is a callback function - where are you trying to return the data to?

Comment: What exactly is `Y`, and where is it supposed to be returned to ?

Comment: Y is an integer, I want to use this variable later.
so for example,
`.on("focusout", X1)`;
and then
`if (Y == 1)` then something

Comment: Any value that an event handler function returns will be ignored, unless it returns `false` which will stop the default behavior of the event (and prevent it from bubbling). This question shows a basic misunderstanding of event handling in Javascript; I suggest you read up on it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the scope of Y to sit outside the scope of the function X1

```
var Y = 0;
var X1 = function () { Y++; };

myelement.on("focusout",X1);

function doCheck() {
   if (Y == 1) {
     //etc...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, in case someone will need it in the future, I found better solution (I think so). In mike d solution there is problem that if this function would be used in some place, where would be not defined `Y` in parent scope, so there will be created global variable. There is better solution:

```
var y = null;
$('div').on('focusout', function() {
    y = X1();
});
```

So, even if there will be not defined `Y` in parent scope, function will work properly. It's more safe.